# Checking value of select tag in html using script tag.. And want to display the value of the dropdown separately in h1 tag.. Code is given below

Tags: javascript, html, select, dropdown, return-value

In this code, I want to check the value of dropdown of the select tag in html. And display it in id='h1'(At the bottom).. Script tag is already there in head tag. There pls write any function to impellent in onchange attribute in select tag. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <script></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="title">
                <p><span style="font-size: 50px;">N</span>avya <span style="font-size: 50px;">M</span>alhotra</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_links">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="pics/Youtube.png" alt="The Source is down" style="height: 45px;"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/navya_malhotra_01/"><img src="pics/Instagram.png" alt="The Source is down" style="height: 33px;"></a></li>
                    <li style="margin-top: 32px;"><a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="pics/Facebook.png" alt="The Source is down" style="height: 29px;"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="home_title"><span style="font-size: 40px;">C</span>ontact <span style="font-size: 40px;">U</span>s</p>    
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" id="" minlength="8" required/>
            <input type="email" required minlength="13"/>
            <input type="number" required minlength="10"/>
            <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown" onchange="" >
                <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                <option value="review">Review</option>
                <option value="query">Query</option>
                <option value="complain">Complaint</option>
                <option value="custom">Custom</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="" id=""/>
            <h1 id="h1"></h1>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```